# Gerar relatório através do Angular para Web API C#

Tags: angular, relatório, asp.net-web-api

Eu estou iniciando a parte do relatório do meu sistema, ao fazer uma requisição para gerar um relatório em uma nova aba eu até consigo fazer por link passando alguns parametros.

```
window.open(this.httpUtil.url('SinistroReports/' + search.DateStart +'/' + search.DateEnd +'/'), "_blank")
```

Mas eu precisava para todo um objeto serializado pelo POST, que até aonde eu sei, eu não consigo passar pelo window.open.

Então eu estou passando os atributos do meu relatório para a minha API / POST e gero o meu relatório, só que precisava que minha API abrisse uma nova aba para visualizar o relatório.

Alguém tem alguma dicas / sugestão de como poderia proceder?